Can the Warlock's Beguiling Defenses trigger on AoE effects?
We had an issue come up on our table regarding The Archfey Warlock's Beguiling Defenses vs an AOE breath weapon.

In addition, immediately after a creature you can see hits you with an attack, you can take a Reaction to reduce the damage by half (round down) and force the attacker to make a DC 18 Wis. saving throw. On a failed save, the attacker takes Psychic damage equal to the damage you take. Once used, you can’t use this Reaction again unless you expend a Pact Magic spell slot to restore your use of it.

The question is, what qualifies as 'hits you with an attack'? I would think an attack roll would count - some attack method with a spell. But what about an AOE Breath Weapon that uses a Dex save? Would that count for the reaction? The AOE, or other similar thing - like Spirit Guardians, Moonbeam, or Sickening Radiance have saving throws and are considered 'hazards' on the battlefield and not attacks.
I ruled that the triggering attack had to have an attack roll to allow Beguiling Defenses to operate. What would you rule and why?

Beguilling Defenses only triggers on attacks
Making an attack is defined on page 25 of the PHB, it can be made with the attack action but also sometimes with a bonus action or reaction. An attack can be with a weapon, unarmed strike or spell, no matter how it is made, it has these characteristics:

It has a a single target (not AoE)
It includes making an attack roll (not just a saving throw)

Beguilling Defenses explicitly only triggers on attacks. Being forced to make a saving throw is not the same as being targeted by an attack. It also only triggers when you are hit by an attack, so if the attack misses you cannot use it either.
